# Undefined variable: "$gray-lighter" in DatePicker CSS

Tags: datepicker, sass, liferay, gulp-sass, liferay-theme

I am building and deploying my liferay theme through liferay-theme-generator
I have sass 3.4.22 version. I have a datepicker.scss version 2.0 in my css folder.
When building it I am having an error `build/_css/datepicker.scss (Line 117: Undefined variable: "$gray-lighter".)`

In build folder, _variables which contains the variable $gray-lighter was there.
Hope someone can give me some light here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an update about this, I was able to fix the issue by adding an import of all variables of bootstrap _variables.scss class in my custom.scss.

Hope it can help others when running into this issue.
cheers!